# Grunt not finding mocha browser tests

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, mocha.js, bower

I am following this tutorial:
https://gist.github.com/maicki/7781943

Here is my **grunt file**:

```
// Gruntfile.js
module.exports = function(grunt){
    grunt.initConfig({
      pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

      //Mocha 
        mocha: {
            all: {
                src: ['tests/spec.html']
            },
            options: {
                run: true,
                reporter: 'Spec',
                growlOnSuccess: false
            }
        }

    });
    //Load grunt mocha task
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-mocha')

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['mocha']);
  };
```

I've setup the following in addition to what this guide has suggested:

```
ran bower init inside of the tests folder.
generating the following:
  "description": "",
  "main": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "test",
    "tests"
  ]
```

I completed this because before running that command the tests weren't being found.

When I run grunt from the command line I get the following:
Testing: tests/spec.html

0 passing (0ms)

> > 0 passed! (0.00s)

Here is a gist with the spec.html page and the webspec.js page with the unit tests:
https://gist.github.com/dhuang612/83dcba46e0a70c107a3e081c5e5dca12

Thank you for any help provided!

Answer (score 0):

I did some more research and found

```
https://github.com/shellscape/mocha-chrome
```

I was able to get this configured to run the browser tests within the command line.
I then used another npm package called concurrently to run both the unit tests and the browser tests at once.